# Find all values in Column A which are present in Column B

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, match

Consider the sheet below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |

I want to find if there is a match for each row of column 1 with any row of column 2. So ideally this would give me:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Yes |
| 3 | 5 | No |
| 2 | 2 | Yes |
| 5 | 0 | Yes |
| 4 | 1 | Yes |

As a first and simple step, I am using `=MATCH(A2,B2:B6)` to get the **index** of the match and then manually calling this across the rows to get something like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | - |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

I am now having a problem:

I want to apply this for a row of 500 in A and 2000 in B. I was thinking of manually filling in the first few rows and then select and drag over the first 500 rows. This however does not work as for each subsequent cell, it just changes the formula to `=MATCH(A(N +1),B2 + N:B6 + N)` which gives me wrong values and at worst, just repeats the older pattern ahead.

Can anyone help me with how I can just use the `MATCH` function to find all the values in A that are present in B?

Comment: Are you on excel or google-sheet?

Comment: Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A501,B2:B2001)),"Yes","No")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me continue where you arrived:

```
=MATCH(A2,B2:B6,0)
```

(You forgot the last zero)

This formula is correct, but it is also wrong.
???

Well, when you drag it down, you get:

```
=MATCH(A3,B3:B7,0)
```

This is not what you want: you want the search term (A2) to change into A3 but you want the search array (B2:B6) not to change. In order to get this done, you need to work with absolute references. This looks like this:

```
=MATCH(A2,B$2:B$6,0)
```

When you drag this down, this is what you get:

```
=MATCH(A3,B$2:B$6,0)
```

=> ok so far.

Problem now: you need to translate your current results (a number or `#N/A`) into "yes" or "no". This can be done in numerous ways, let me give you an example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$6,0)),"No","Yes")
```

One remark: there exists an `IFERROR()` function in Excel, but this does not have an "else"-clause, hence the choice for the `IF(ISERROR(` combination.

Answer (score 0):

Within Sheets you may try this out:

```
=index(if(len(A2:A),if(ifna(xmatch(A2:A,B2:B)),"Yes","No"),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate those matching values then could use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,COUNTIFS(B1:B9,A1:A5))
```

And for `YES`, `NO` dynamically, try `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(x,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,B:B))))
```

[image]